# I cannot crawl HTML text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In my previous question([How to speed up parsing using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794997/how-to-speed-up-parsing-using-beautifulsoup)), I asked the way to crawl HTML website more quickly, and the answer helped me much.

But I encountered another problem. It is about crawling the price of tickets.

I got JSON text in the webpage referring the answer of my previous question. I could get almost every information about festivals in the JSON, such as title, date, location, poster image url, and performers.

But there was no info about pricing, so I tried to get the price in other part of the website.

When I turned on Google Chrome developer mode, there is a table about pricing (It includes Korean, but you don't have to understand it):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col style="width:20px;">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody id="divSalesPrice">
        <tr>
            <td>2일권(입장권)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="costTd">
                <span>140,000 원</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1일권(입장권)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="costTd">
                <span>88,000 원</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Numbers in span tag (140000, 80000) are the prices I want to extract. So I thought using Soup will be effective:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def Soup(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    return soup


def DetailLink(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = Soup(req.content)
    spans = soup.findAll('span', class_='fw_bold')
    links = [f'{url[:27]}{span.a["href"]}' for span in spans]
    return links


def Price():
    links = DetailLink('http://ticket.interpark.com/TPGoodsList.asp?Ca=Liv&SubCa=Fes')
    with requests.Session() as request:
        for link in links:
            req = request.get(link)
            soup = Soup(req.content)
            price = soup.find('tbody', id='divSalesPrice')
            print(price)


Price()
```

However, the result was disappointing...

```
<tbody id="divSalesPrice">
<!-- 등록된 기본가 가져오기 오류-->
<tr>
<td colspan="3" id="liBasicPrice">
<ul>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The comment '등록된 기본가 가져오기 오류' means 'An error occurred while getting the price.'

Is it means that a website operator blocked other users to crawl price info in the page?

Comment: Does your code work when you locally save the web page first and use that as input?

Comment: @usr2564301 No. In the saved HTML file, there is also a comment about error.

Comment: good day dear bongbong - many thanks for the reply - i am glad. But if i try to run this on MX-Linux on a ATOM i get back the following: `  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_ticket_interpark.py", line 14
    links = [f'{url[:27]}{span.a["href"]}' for span in spans]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.507s]` - whiy is this so - i have no glue at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if we look carefully, the price data is not get when you request the page, it's loaded afterwards, that means we need to get the price data from somewhere else.

If you inspect the network section in chrome, there is this strange url:

[image]

And it has the data you look for:

[image]

Now the only thing you need to do is get the place id and product id. You can get these from homepage as you can see:

[image]

The `vPC` is the location id and `vGC` is the product id, you can get the product id from url too.

Then this code explains the rest:

```py
import requests, re, json

# Just a random product url, you can adapt the code into yours.
url = "http://ticket.interpark.com/Ticket/Goods/GoodsInfo.asp?GroupCode=20002746"

data = requests.get(url).text

# I used regex to get the matching values `vGC` and `vPC`
vGC = re.search(r"var vGC = \"(\d+)\"", data).groups()[0]
vPC = re.search(r"var vPC = \"(\d+)\"", data).groups()[0]

# Notice that I placed placeholders to use `format`. Placeholders are `{}`.
priceUrl = "http://ticket.interpark.com/Ticket/Goods/GoodsInfoJSON.asp?Flag=SalesPrice&GoodsCode={}&PlaceCode={}"

# Looks like that url needs a referer url and that is the goods page, we will pass it as header.
lastData = requests.get(priceUrl.format(vGC, vPC), headers={"Referer": url}).text

# As the data is a javascript object but inside it is a json object,
# we can remove the callback and parse the inside of callback as json data:
lastData = re.search(r"^Callback\((.*)\);$", lastData).groups()[0]
lastData = json.loads(lastData)["JSON"]

print(lastData)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'DblDiscountOrNot': 'N',
  'GoodsName': '뷰티풀 민트 라이프 2020 - 공식 티켓',
  'PointDiscountAmt': '0',
  'PriceGradeName': '입장권',
  'SalesPrice': '140000',
  'SeatGradeName': '2일권'},
 {'DblDiscountOrNot': 'N',
  'GoodsName': '뷰티풀 민트 라이프 2020 - 공식 티켓',
  'PointDiscountAmt': '0',
  'PriceGradeName': '입장권',
  'SalesPrice': '88000',
  'SeatGradeName': '1일권'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Your code acts perfectly. But why can't I see contents in JSON when I go to the url "http://ticket.interpark.com/Ticket/Goods/GoodsInfoJSON.asp?Flag=SalesPrice&GoodsCode=20002746&PlaceCode=15710344&Point=N&Callback=fnSalesPriceCallBackJSON" directly in a web browser? I can only see an empty string.

Comment: Because as I wrote in the comments, the header `Referer` is required for some reason, that's why we passed the product url here.

Comment: If you ask how could I possibly know whether to put `Referer` here or not, I tried directly sending the same request as the page requested, then removed unnecesary parameters, headers and etc. until I am unable to get the data. And it was that moment that I was unable to get the data when I removed header `Referer`.

Comment: Then is it means that the price data page can be opened successfully only when the attribute `Referer` have the correct value? In other words, did the page developer intend that users can open the price data page only through the ticket sale page?

Comment: Yes and no, I checked the request again and used only `http://ticket.interpark.com/` as `Referer` and it worked. Looks like developer is intended to accept requests only if the request is from that domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I cite your answer in my blog post? I want to translate it to my language and share this useful information with others.

Comment: Sure, no problem :) Can I get a link when you post it?

Comment: Here is my post. It's written in Korean. https://arzt.tistory.com/7